# Count Records Per Day Per Hour , Where/Having Clause issue

Tags: sql

I have query that is calculating HourlyCountPerDay. It works fine until i add Where or Having Clause on st.Occurred. 
Query is

```
  SELECT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, st.Occurred), 0) AS DateHourStamp,
  COUNT(*) AS TotalCount,at.[Key] 
  FROM  dbo.SomeTable st INNER JOIN             
  dbo.AnotherTable at ON st.ID = at.ID 
  GROUP BY  DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, st.Occurred), 0), at.Key 
  ORDER BY  DateHourStamp DESC
```

and below is result

```
DateHourStamp     TotalCount    Key
2/17/15 14:00 PM     41         A22F0D83-544E-4AE9-B426-D12B2F98E239
2/17/15 14:00 PM     42         DD1E803B-76C9-4D74-8E08-CF36FD074A36
2/17/15 13:00 PM     85         DD1E803B-76C9-4D74-8E08-CF36FD074A36
2/17/15 14:00 PM     54         A22F0D83-544E-4AE9-B426-D12B2F98E239
```

Which is Right so far. Now as soon as i add below in Having or Where Clause it

```
HAVING (DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0,st.Occurred), 0) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-02-14', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-02-17', 102) )
```

It changes the whole count figure to wrong count and the time to 00:00. I have spent like more than couple of hours?

Any thoughts what i am doing wrong? i am using 2008r2, but it has to be work on 2005

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in that HAVING clause?

Comment: I am trying to grab records that's between specified dates

Comment: The result you show doesn't match the code you've given (the order of the result is not `DateHourStamp DESC`), and the tablename in your `HAVING` or `WHERE` clause doesn't match the query either.  I would expect that an appropriate `WHERE` clause should meet your requirements.  You don't need to do an explicit `CONVERT` to datetime if you use an unambiguous format, e.g. '2015-02-14 09:00'.  Please post an EXACT query that you have run, and the results you get.

Comment: I don't see TL anywhere in your first query yet it's an alias in the HAVING?

Comment: It's more natural to put your expression in a WHERE clause but I believe is should operate the same way as a HAVING regardless. I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @TobyLL  i truncated the dataset, its a huge dataset and i changed the table names. Instead of TL.Occurred its st.occurred and that's the Exact query i wrote.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the below should work. Pay attention to the dates range. In your example all DateHourStamp are 2/17/15. With range till '2015-02-17' (which for SQL server datetime is '2015-02-17 00:00:00) they won't be included. To include whole day od 2/17/15 the range should end '2015-02-18' (which is 2015-02-18 00:00:00) or  2015-02-17 23:59:59 (or use < 2015-02-18)

```
 SELECT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, st.Occurred), 0) AS DateHourStamp,
      COUNT(*) AS TotalCount,at.[Key] 
      FROM  dbo.SomeTable st INNER JOIN             
      dbo.AnotherTable at ON st.ID = at.ID

    where (DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0,TL.Occurred), 0) BETWEEN '2015-02-14' AND '2015-02-17'

      GROUP BY  DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, st.Occurred), 0), at.Key 
      ORDER BY  DateHourStamp DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're losing the day of the 17th except for the hour that falls at midnight.

Change the end of the range to something like this:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-02-17 23:00', 102)
```